# Google Map API overwrite CSS style

Tags: css, google-maps-api-3

I have a problem that Google Map API is inheriting the style from my webpage which results in this:

[image]

Is there a way to let Google Map ignore the style of my website which would solve the issue. This is the div I use

```
<p><div id="map_all" style="width:100%; height: 400px"></div></p>
```

The problem is the background:

```
img {
background: #FAFAFA;
border: 1px solid #DCDCDC;
padding: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Would need to see the code - both html and css. Preferably the whole page.

Comment: I have edited the post. The problem is the background: ... i tried to use a custom css for #map_all {} but that does not work.

Comment: Can you apply that style only to images of certain class?

Comment: looks like i found the solution... main problem was the browsercache.. it did not reflect the changes I have done on the CSS :(... thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind. I just fixed the issue by adding the following

```
#map_all img {
background: none;
}
```

and cleared the browsercache. Now it works.